# Can't run Popen.communicate() twice. (Python subprocess module)

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Can anyone explain why I get this error if I run the communicate function twice?

For instance

```
from subprocess import *
SVN=Popen('which svn', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
print SVN.communicate()[0]
```

returns

```
"/usr/bin/svn"
```

but running communicate again...

```
print SVN.communicate()[0]
```

returns...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",     line 746, in communicate
stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
return func(*args)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the "file", which is actually the stdout of the program being invoked, has been closed.  This means you have already read all the output in the previous `communicate()`, so calling it again can never produce anything.